# Is there a way to make the ini file easy to see?

Tags: c#, ini

I made a INI file using C# script (`GetPrivateProfileString`, `WritePrivateProfileString`)

and the result is below

```
[SectionA]
valueA=0
valueB=1
valueC=2
[SectionB]
valueD=0
valueE=1
valueF=2
```

but this file is hard to see
The results I want are as follows.

```
[SectionA]
valueA=0
valueB=1
valueC=2

[SectionB]
valueD=0
valueE=1
valueF=2
```

To make like this, i wrote `valueC`'s value with `\n`
However, if the order was different, I had strange results.
like this

```
[SectionA]
valueC=2

valueA=0
valueB=1
[SectionB]
valueD=0
valueE=1
valueF=2
```

So I want to know how to make this.
Please let me know

Comment: `GetPrivateProfileString` appears to be a C++/kernel method. Can you [edit] your post with a [mre] of the code you're using to write the file?

Comment: @gunr2171 I used `DllImport` to use `GetPrivateProfileString` and `WritePrivateProfileString` method

Comment: If you're looping over each of sectionA and sectionB you could just insert '\n' between the two. If not, try sharing the script you used to make this file and maybe someone smarter than me can help.

Comment: Get/WritePrivateProfileString are both native WinAPI functions. The output can't be controlled; the format is pretty well fixed, and it doesn't allow any adjustments. INI files are usually meant to be read/written programmatically to contain configuration information.

Comment: Is there a reason why you have to use those two WinAPI functions, instead of reading/writing to the file yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Read to string and:

```
Replace("[","\n["));
Replace("\n\n\n","\n\n");   //prevent from depulicated "\n"
Replace("\n[SectionA]","[SectionA]");    //delete the first "\n"
```

Write string to file